# Spring-boot simplest way to express projections

Tags: spring-boot, projection

There are a simple way to use `@Projection` in this context?

My *Report* entity have big fields (eg. a *content* field with a full HTML text) that I not need to deliver at the endpoint.

```java
@Repository
public interface IReportRepository extends BaseRepository<Report, Long> {

    List<Report> findAll();  // working fine... BUT with fields that not need

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "SELECT id, acronym FROM report")
    List<Object[]> findSomeFields1();  // BAD JSON, no field name!

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "SELECT id, acronym FROM report")
    List<Map> findSomeFields2();  // ERROR! Failed to convert
         // there are something as JSON Row Mapper?

}
```

(them the *ReportController* deliver it as JSON at the endpoint, only it)

**Instead a `@Query` I need to use `@Projection(...)`**... How to use it (the **simplest** way!)?

Comment: is it also ok for you that you use `findAll()` method and just do not export some fields of report to the user in general?

Comment: Hi @Patrick, is to findAll() from the specific (native) query, returning only the expected fields, with structured data, as in entity findAll().

Comment: Do you have to use `@Projection` or are you fine with other solutions without using it?

Comment: Need the simplicity of `@Projection` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an example from the Spring Project repository you could check this project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections

Anyway, if you want to have more control of your obtained data, you could use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) and [Springlets](https://github.com/DISID/springlets) libraries to return projections from your Spring Data Repositories.

Here's an example about how to use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) and [Springlets](https://github.com/DISID/springlets) together:

Create a new class that contains only the concrete fields you want to obtain. For example, for a `Owner` entity, you could create the `OwnerInfo` projection that only contains `id`, `firstName` and `lastName` fields.

```
public class OwnerInfo {

  private Long id;

  @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
  private String firstName;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
  private String lastName;

}
```

Following the `Owner` example, creates a new repository interface called `OwnerRepositoryCustom` and define the finder that will return the projection.

```
public interface OwnerRepositoryCustom {

  public Page<OwnerInfo> findByFirstNameLike(String firstName, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Creates the implementation of our `OwnerRepositoryCustom`. This class should extends `QueryDslRepositorySupportExt` from [Springlets](https://github.com/DISID/springlets) project.

```
public class OwnerRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupportExt<Owner> implements OwnerRepositoryCustom {

    OwnerRepositoryImpl() {
        super(Owner.class);
    }

    public Page<OwnerInfo> findByFirstNameLike(String firstName, Pageable pageable) {

        QOwner owner = QOwner.owner;

        JPQLQuery<Owner> query = from(owner);

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(firstName)) {
           BooleanBuilder searchCondition = new BooleanBuilder();                         

           searchCondition.and(owner.firstName.eq(firstName));

           if (searchCondition.hasValue()) {
            query.where(searchCondition);
           }
        }

        Path<?>[] paths = new Path<?>[] {owner.id,owner.firstName,owner.lastName};        

        AttributeMappingBuilder mapping = buildMapper()
            .map(ID, owner.id)
            .map(FIRST_NAME, owner.firstName)
            .map(LAST_NAME, owner.lastName);

        return loadPage(query, pageable, Projections.constructor(OwnerInfo.class, owner.id, owner.firstName, owner.lastName));
    }

}
```

Now, extend the `OwnerRepository` interface from `JpaRepository<Owner, Long> and`OwnerRepositoryCustom` interface.

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends OwnerRepositoryCustom, JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {

}
```

With that simple steps, you will be able to return projections in your repository methods.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! Good choices and explanations. About simplicity of `@Query` and `@Projection`, no direct solution?  imagine query `SELECT id, acronym FROM report` with some projection specification for `(id,acronym)`...

Comment: Following the examples from the Spring blog, seems like if you create a `ReportInfo` projection annotated with `@Projection(name="report", types = Report.class))` and defines that projection as return type of your operation `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value= "SELECT id, acronym FROM report")
    List<ReportInfo> findSomeFields1();  // BAD JSON, no field name!` Spring Data should return a valid projection object. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am on holidays, but will test, thanks a lot... It seems the core of the answer (!), can you show the `@Projection` code lines as fragment of my *IReportRepository*  class?  (no *entity* declaration need?)

Comment: (about bounty) Hi, I am waiting a "simple solution" in the answer text, using `@Projection` as your comment above... The answer, at this moment, have good  explanations but the same complexity than [usual](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) `interface Specification` solutions.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll advert you if I find out some simple solution!